# CSS Rotate move others elements in the page

Tags: css, animation

when i hover the strong pink words,they rotate … but move also the text inside the boxes below. how can i fix it ?

[Example](http://salmen88.altervista.org/)

Comment: not seeing the problem in chrome (on osx).  what browser are you using?

Comment: i'm with chrome in Mavericks , i have the same problem with safari

Comment: I'm experiencing it with Chrome on Windows but not Firefox. If I remove the rotation from `.diamond` and `.content` the problem goes away.

Comment: I have to keep the rotation in .diamond and .content

Comment: I was just saying the problem seems related to that. If you make it so the text is not a child of the diamond and doesn't have to be rotated, that might avoid the issue.